# ERRORLEVEL vs %ERRORLEVEL% vs exclamation mark ERRORLEVEL exclamation mark

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I think i have a basic understanding of ERRORLEVEL vs %ERRORLEVEL% but !ERRORLEVEL! confuses me.

I'm making a script that calls an executable, then tasklist to see if its running, then taskkill to kill it if it is and then trying to output the errorlevels and repeating for other exe's and i'm realising i really don't understand errorlevels in batch.

I set a variable equal to !errorlevel! 
then used that variable without quotation marks in an echo, and the variable changed from one uint16 to another uint16 when there was an error after the set, like its a reference to the real one instead of a copy. I want copy. Can someone explain the difference between these guys?

---

Update:
Here is the snippet I'm working on.

```
for %%P in (%executableList%) do (
   echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    set exeErrorlevel=0
    set running=false

    start %%~fP  
    set exeErrorlevel=!ERRORLEVEL!

    rem for debugging purposes
    echo %%~nP%%~xP older errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL%       
    echo %%~nP%%~xP newer errorlevel !ERRORLEVEL!        
    echo before tasklist running var is : !running!

    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%~fP" | find /I /N /C  "%%~fP" >nul && set running=true

    echo after tasklist is running var is: !running!

    if !running! equ true ( 
       echo %%~nP%%~xP Program is running
       taskkill /F /IM %%~nP%%~xP /T
       echo %%~nP%%~xP Program was killed          

       if !exeErrorlevel! == 0 (
           echo %passString% %%~nP%%~xP process was started and killed safely 
           echo %passString% %%~nP%%~xP process was started and killed safely >>%outputfile%
       ) else ( 
           echo %failString% %%~nP%%~xP process was killed with errorcode !exeErrorlevel!
           echo %failString% %%~nP%%~xP process was killed with errorcode !exeErrorlevel! >>%outputfile%                  
       )         
    ) else (             
         if !exeErrorlevel! == 0 (
             echo %passString% %%~nP%%~xP process exited safely
             echo %passString% %%~nP%%~xP process exited safely >>%outputfile%
         ) else (                 
             taskkill /F /IM %%~nP%%~xP /T
             echo %failString% %%~nP%%~xP process abruptly exited with errorcode !exeErrorlevel! 
             echo %failString% %%~nP%%~xP process abruptly exited with errorcode !exeErrorlevel! >>%outputfile%                  
         )                    
    )

    echo. >>%outputfile%


)
```

I need to make sure exeErrorlevel has a copy of the errorlevel at a certain point in time - I only want to capture errors from the exe, not from the success/failure of tasklist/find/taskill. I'm concerned that exeerrorlevel, because of the delayed expansion, is accessing the delayed errorlevel upon execution. perhaps that should be set exeErrorlevel=%errorlevel% instead. In the line where i echo older and newer variables usually return different integers? In all my test runs %errorlevel% seems to typically return 0 whereas !errorlevel! is consistently non zero for executables with bad exit codes.

Comment: From the description it seems you assigned `var=!errorlevel!` without delayed expansion active and then executed `echo %var%` with delayed expansion active, but without seeing the code we are just guessing.

Comment: Pretty sure "!" around a variable does nothing for variable expansion if delayed expansion isn't active, it'd treat it like a string.....I've got setlocal enabledextension delayedexpansion at the top of my bat. All I want to know is the difference between those three at the top. I want to know how they work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The errorlevel*

`errorlevel` is the name of a dynamic variable (it is not placed in the environment block but hold in memory) that stores the exit code of the previous executed process/command (if it sets that value, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34968009/2861476), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34987885/2861476), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30714985/2861476) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41318027/2861476)).

The `if` command allows the usage of the `if errorlevel n` syntax to check if the value of the `errorlevel` variable is greater than or equal to `n`, without involving the batch parser into retrieving the value of the variable.

But, if we put the batch parser to work with variable values, `%errorlevel%` is just a reference to the value stored in the variable, a read operation. Just the same as `!errorlevel!`.  The main difference between the two is **when** the value is retrieved depending on the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2861476) on variable expansion.

There is a great difference in using the `if errorlevel` or retrieving the value in the variable:

- The variable read operation will check if the environment block contains a variable with the indicated name.
- The `if` constuct will not make this test.

If you do something like `set errorlevel=10`, the dynamic `errorlevel` value will not be retrieved with `%errorlevel%` or `!errorlevel!` as the value set in the environment will hide the dynamic value. But as `if errorlevel` does not read the environment block but directly reads the internal variable that holds the value, it will work without problems.

*The variables*

The batch syntax does not include the option of having more than one variable pointing to the same value in memory in a way that if one of the variables changes its value, the other will reflect the change.

This behaviour can be simulated by proper use of the different phases in variable expansion, properly setting a variable to the name of another and forcing the batch parser to do two passes over the command so first variable is resolved to the name of the second and that to the real value.

*Your problem*

Simplified (non even working) code just for analysis

```dos
 1  for %%P in (%executableList%) do (
 2  
 3      start %%~fP  
 4      set exeErrorlevel=!ERRORLEVEL!
 5  
 6      echo %%~nP%%~xP older errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL%       
 7      echo %%~nP%%~xP newer errorlevel !ERRORLEVEL!        
 8      ....
 9      if !running! equ true ( 
10         taskkill /F /IM %%~nP%%~xP /T
11         if !exeErrorlevel! == 0 (
12          ....
13         ) else ( 
14             echo process killed with errorcode !exeErrorlevel!
15         )         
16      ) else (             
17           if !exeErrorlevel! == 0 (
18             ....
19           ) else (                 
20               taskkill /F /IM %%~nP%%~xP /T
21               echo process abruptly exited with errorcode !exeErrorlevel! 
22           )                    
23      )
```

- line 1: the code in the `do` clause, all the code, is parsed. Any `%var%` variable read operation is removed from the code, replaced with the value inside the variable before starting the execution. This means that if the variable changes its value you will not be able to retrieve the changed value as the read operation does not exist, only the initial value in the variable.
- line 3: the executable is launched, in a separate process, without waiting for the process to end. Is it important? See next line
- line 4: the current (delayed expansion used) value of the `errorlevel` variable is retrieved and stored in `exeErrorlevel` variable. BUT the value stored is NOT the `errorlevel` returned by the executable (separate process, not waiting for it to end, how will we know what the `exit code = errorlevel` is?), but the exit code of the `start` command.
- line 6: as the `%errorlevel%` read operation was removed, this line will echo the value that was stored in the `errorlevel` variable before the `do` clause started to execute.
- line 7: the current value of the `errorlevel` variable is retrieved. And here, we can have a problem. How the script being executed is named? There is a difference between `.bat` and `.cmd`. On sucess the `set` command in line 4 will clear (set to 0) the `errorlevel` variable if this is a `.cmd` file, but will not change the `errorlevel` if it is a `.bat` file.
- lines 11, 14, 21: as seen the `exeErrorlevel` variable does not contain a valid value. And no, changing the lines to `!errorlevel!` will not retrieve the exit code of the process, but the exit code of the `taskkill`.

To be able to retrieve the exit code / errorlevel of a process we need to wait for it to end. If you need to start the process, if it keeps running kill it, and in both cases retrieve the exit code, directly call the executable or use `start "" /wait programName`, AND run the killing process in parallel (ex. `start /b "" monitor.bat programName` or something similar before starting the program). The main process will wait and retrieve the exit code. The monitor process handles the killing.

Comment: Thank you for your links. I've updated the question with my code and am realising maybe I don't understand delayed variable expansion properly. Thank you for clarifying that set does not store a pointer, but a copy.

Comment: line 3: many of my exe processes don't end. I thought that waiting for them would be silly.
line 4: some do end. if the process exits by itself, won't that code get propagated to the start command and since nothing else happens between line 3 and 4 that could clear the exitcode, shouldn't it be the errorlevel returned by the exe if it exited and 0 if it didn't? 
line 6: if its before the do, if i change the value in one iteration, will it be different when do is evaluated before the start of the next iteration? or does it all happen once before and thus the same value for all iterations.

Comment: line 11,14,21: that's why I tried to save the errorlevel prior. Also, I noticed that often !exeErrorLevel! would be evaluated to not 0, but then in stdout it prints 0.

I will implement your suggestions, but what does the "" do before the start command?

Comment: @user2309274, **line 4** No, after a `start` (without `/wait`) command you get the `errorlevel` of the `start` not the one of the program. **line 6** as said, once the *full* `for` command is parsed, there is not any `%var%` read operation, only the values contained in the variables at parse time, the same initial value for all iterations. *""* the `start` command handles its first quoted argument as a window title, if your command needs quotes (ex. spaces in file name, path, ...) you need to include the window title (`""` = empty window title)