# wrong value of %errorlevel% in nested if in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel, delayedvariableexpansion

I have written a `.bat` file to first run a program, if it is correctly finished I run another program and check return value of it.

```
first-program.exe
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    second-program.exe
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        ECHO OK
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO NOK
    )
)
```

However the second `%ERRORLEVEL%` is always equal to first, it doesn't set to the return value of `second-program.exe`.

Comment: Did you try it using delayed expansion?

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the `ErrorLevel` after `second-program.exe` as it is updated in the same block of code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERRORLEVEL vs %ERRORLEVEL% vs exclamation mark ERRORLEVEL exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967840/errorlevel-vs-errorlevel-vs-exclamation-mark-errorlevel-exclamation-mark)

Comment: Depending upon the 'programs', you may just be able to do this `"First-Program.exe" && ( "Second-Program.exe" && ( Echo OK ) || Echo NOK )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both instances of `%ERRORLEVEL%` are in the same block of code and thus *both* get their values at the moment when the first instance is updated. Consider enabling delayed expansion of variables with `enabledelayedexpansion` and replacing `%ERRORLEVEL%` with `!ERRORLEVEL!` to update each instance individually. For instance:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
first-program.exe
IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
    second-program.exe
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
        ECHO OK
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO NOK
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: I only had a single instance of `%ERRORLEVEL%` in my script, and it was incorrectly returning 0. I changed it to `!ERRORLEVEL!` and my script seems to work now. Though I'm still not exactly sure why. The `enabledelayedexpansion` setting is quite ambiguous to me at this moment.

Comment: @velcoon, this can't be answered for sure without seeing your code, but guess that the probable reason can be that you have %ERRORLEVEL% inside an IF or FOR cycle. To be on the safe side, better always use delayed expansion inside cycles.